# how to follow page redirect and persistently set constant browser useragent using phantomjs and php-webdriver

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I don't know if my logic is right but this is what i'm thinking to solve cookies required restriction or inability to login via auth login pages (e.g. facebook) with using phantomjs headless browser and php-webdriver.

Quite alright, that first instance will set user agent to that of a  browser when accessing a url, but there can be a browser test by redirecting (either through meta or javascript redirect) to another page to validate the useragent as well as cookies.

I extracted a code snippet from bpteam/php-cookie to obtain cookies from a preconfigured cookie file, which is here below

```
<?php
$cookiedata = file_get_contents("/usr/share/nginx/html/php-webdriver/cookies.txt");

//from bpteam/php-cookie
function parsCookieString($text){
    $parameters = ['expires', 'domain', 'path'];
    if(preg_match('%^\s*(?<name>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<value>[^;]+)%ims', $text, $match)){
        $cookie['name'] = trim($match['name']);
        $cookie['value'] = trim($match['value']);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    foreach($parameters as $param){
        if(preg_match('%' . $param . '\s*=\s*(?<val>[^;]+)%i', $text, $match)){
            $cookie[$param] = trim($match['val']);
        }
    }
    $cookie['secure'] = (bool)preg_match('%;\s*secure\s*(;|$)%i', $text);
    $cookie['httponly'] = (bool)preg_match('%;\s*httponly\s*(;|$)%i', $text);
    return $cookie;
}
function from($text){
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    $regexDelimiter = '(?:(?:\\\\n)?((\\\\0|\\\\{2}|((\\\\x[0-9a-f]{2}){2}|\\\\x[0-9a-f]{2})|\\\\x[0-9a-f]|\\\\_|\\\\[abtnvfr]|[g-zG-Z]|\W|\\\\\W)))';
    $regexLine = "%^cookies=\"?\@Variant\(({$regexDelimiter}{4}){2}QList\\<QNetworkCookie\\>\\\\0({$regexDelimiter}{4}){2}(?<cookie_str>.*)\)\"?\s*$%ms";
    if(!isset($lines[1]) || !preg_match($regexLine, $lines[1], $match)){
        return array();
    }
    $delimiter = 'REPLACE_COOKIE_DELIMITER';
    $regEx = "\\\\0\\\\0\\\\0".$regexDelimiter;
    $text = preg_replace("%$regEx%ms", $delimiter, $match['cookie_str']);
    $cookiesLines = explode($delimiter, $text);
    $cookies = array();
    foreach ($cookiesLines as $cookieLine) {
        $cookie = parsCookieString($cookieLine);
        if($cookie){
            $cookies[] = $cookie;
        }
    }
    return $cookies;
}
$cookies = from($cookiedata);
?>
```

And this is what I'm trying to do that couldn't succeed in trying to login via auth login page (e.g. facebook).

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
//require_once('visidom.php');
require_once('cookie.php');

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::phantomjs();

$capabilities->setCapability(
    'phantomjs.cli.args',
    ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--web-security=false','--cookies-file=/usr/share/nginx/html/php-webdriver/cookies.txt','--webdriver=4444']
);
$capabilities->setCapability(
    'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'
);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities,5000);

$window = new WebDriverDimension(1024, 768);
$driver->manage()->window()->setSize($window);
@chmod('/usr/share/nginx/html/php-webdriver/cookies.txt',0777);

$driver->get('https://facebook.com');

foreach($cookies as $cookie)
    $driver->manage()->addCookie($cookie); //here i'm trying to add cookie

$driver->wait(10,1000)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
        WebDriverBy::xpath('.//input[@id="email"]')
    )
);

$inputUsername = $driver->findElement(
    WebDriverBy::xpath('.//input[@id="email"]')
);
$inputUsername->sendKeys('<your username>');

$driver->wait(10,1000)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
        WebDriverBy::xpath('.//input[@id="pass"]')
    )
);

$inputPassword = $driver->findElement(
    WebDriverBy::xpath('.//input[@id="pass"]')
);
$inputPassword->sendKeys('<your password>');

$driver->wait(10,1000)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
        WebDriverBy::xpath('.//label[@id="loginbutton"]')
    )
);

$button = $driver->findElement(
    WebDriverBy::xpath('.//label[@id="loginbutton"]')
);
$button->click();

$driver->takeScreenshot('./screen.png');
?>
```

how can one follow a page redirect and persistently set constant browser user agent in phantomjs and monitor response headers to constantly set cookie information to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difficulties occurs because phantomjs doesn't preserve session cookies, so I followed a solution provided on this link https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12277 to solve the problem.